# C/C++: Building a project consisting of interdependent subprojects with netbeans 7.1.2

Tags: c++, eclipse, netbeans, eclipse-cdt, dependency-management

I am building an application framework which consists of several subcomponents (shared libraries and actual applications).

I want to use netbeans 7.1.2 to build the project. However, in the past, I have only built monolithic C/C++ applications with Netbeans.

I have searched in vain to find instructions on how to use netbeans to create/build a project with multiple interdependent sub projects (similar to the concept of a "solution" in the .Net world).

Has anyone ever managed to build a C project consisting of interdependent sub project using Netbeans and/or is there a link that shows how to do this?

**[[Update]]**

It looks like this is a [known missing feature](http://wiki.netbeans.org/CNDProjectsGroupsSpec) or am I missing something (pun unintended).

If Netbeans can't cope with this and Eclipse can, this would be a good time to move to Eclipse (I have downloaded Juno and am familiarizing myself with the GUI now ...)